# What filesystem has best support for shrinking?

Tags: filesystems, lvm

Most mainstream filesystems can be grown fairly reliably, but what if I think I would like to shrink in future?

XFS is a non runner. Reiser seems to have good support but gives scary BETA warnings , it works really fast though. Btrfs seems to promise good things but I've no experience with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

resize2fs is able to both grow and shrink ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems.

Comment: Is it also considered reliable ?

Comment: @barrymac it is reliable, you can even resize the ext3/ext4 filesystem online (as long as your kernel support it, which is almost sure to be).